# Como manipular os dados passado por response no jQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, data, momentjs

Logo após fazer um render de uma tela como no exemplo abaixo:

```
( return res.status(200).render("mschedule", { erro: {}, list: teste }) )
```

Gostaria de manipular um dado de retorno (list) no jquery.

Como consigo tratar (list) que foi passado no render no front para exibir a data formatada

Ex: `list.data(11/03/2019)`, gostaria de pegar esse dado no Jquery do front e formatar essa data para o formato "segunda 11 de maio de 2019".

Comment: Poderia detalhar um pouco mais a sua pergunta?

Comment: Esse 'response' voce consegue isso de onde, dum AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a resposta que eu queria era essa, usei um Framework moment para ter um retorno mais personalizado das datas

const moment = require('moment')
moment.updateLocale('pt-br', {
  months: [
    "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"
  ],
  weekdays: [
    "SEG", "TER", "QUA", "QUI", "SEX", "SAB", "DOM"
  ]
});

aqui eu alterei o retorno desejado

let data = await app.db('viewc')
        .select('*')
        .orderBy('date', 'desc')
        .orderBy('time', 'desc')
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].date = moment(data[i].date).format('DD/MMMM')
        data[i].day = moment(data[i].date).format('dddd')
      }

Answer (score 0):

**Entao, se eu entendi bem, voce quer algo como isto:**

```js
data = new Date("2017-08-21");
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
console.log(
  'A data é:',
  data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', options)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```